# What really happened to Woodsman's daughter in "Over the Garden Wall"?

Tags: plot-explanation, over-the-garden-wall

I'm confused about the ending of *[Over the Garden Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over_the_Garden_Wall)*, where the lonely Woodsman is suddenly surprised by his daughter stepping out of his house. This never really made sense for me.

Throughout the miniseries, it was implied that the Woodsman's lantern carried the soul of his daughter, and he is not to let it perish. At the end, Wirt figures out that it's not the Woodsman's daughter's soul, but the Beast's.

So where was the Woodsman's daughter all this time? And why does she appear out of nowhere after the lantern is blown out? Something must have happened to her to force the Woodsman to "wander the forest for eternity", which Wirt strategically avoided.

Answer (score 2):

In the comic (very worth reading), the woodsman and his wife move to the country from the city with their daughter.  Over several years they become accustomed but the mother passes away. From what I remember, the daughter is out foraging and gets lost, and the woodsman searches for her but is tricked by the beast into the unknown.  The daughter is left at the home waiting for her father.

The comic is wonderful!